# PHP and MySQL query based on user input not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

I am creating a users database where there are 4 fields: ID, username, password, and occupation. This is a test database. I tried querying the db table and it worked but i have a lot of trouble having a user input and a MySQL query based off of it. I run an Apache server in Linux (Debian, Ubuntu).

I have 2 pages. The first one is a bare-bone test index page. this is where there are textboxes for people to input easy info to register their info in the db. Here is the code for it:

```html
<html>
<form action="reg.php" method="POST">
  Username:
  <input type="text" name="u">Password:
  <input type="password" name="p">Occupation:
  <input type="text" name="o">
  <input type="submit" value="register">


</form>

</html>
```

After the submit button is clicked. It goes to the reg.php file. This is where it gets complicated. The page goes blank!!! Nothing is displayed or inputted in the db. Normal queries work well, but when user interaction is added, something is wrong. Here is the code for reg.php:

```html
<?php
$un = $_POST["u"]
$pk = $_POST["p"]
$ok = $_POST["o"]
$u = mysql_real_escape_string($un);
$p = mysql_real_escape_string($pk);  
$o = mysql_real_escape_string($ok);    

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'randompassword');
if (!$link){
die(' Oops. We Have A Problem Here: ' . mysql_error());
}

if ($link){
echo 'connected succesfully';
}

mysql_select_db("forum") or die(' Oops. We Have A Problem Here: ' . mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, occupation) VALUES ('{$u}', '{$p}', '{$o}')");

?>
```

Can anyone hep me to correct this code to make this work?
Thank you so much for your time. Much appreciated.

EDIT:
I noticed that i did not add semicolons in the first 3 lines. after doing so i got this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{'', '', '')' at line 1." Can someone explain why?

EDIT:  the website is just on my local machine...
on an apache server on linux

Comment: Counter question: Is this site going LIVE?

Comment: Blank page means: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: no. The site s not live right now...

Comment: Good. Store hashes, and not string literals for password storage. Plus, error reporting would have signaled the parse error.

Comment: All that dies makes me want to cry :'(

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

I noticed that i did not add semicolons in the first 3 lines. after doing so i got this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{'', '', '')' at line 1." Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` requires a db connection.
Try this ....

```
<?php
$un = $_POST["u"];
$pk = $_POST["p"];
$ok = $_POST["o"];

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'randompassword');
if (!$link){
  die(' Oops. We Have A Problem Here: ' . mysql_error());
}

if ($link){
  echo 'connected succesfully';
}

mysql_select_db("forum") or die(' Oops. We Have A Problem Here: ' . mysql_error());

$u = mysql_real_escape_string($un);
$p = mysql_real_escape_string($pk);
$o = mysql_real_escape_string($ok);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, occupation) VALUES ('$u', '$p', '$o')";
$ins_sql = mysql_query($sql);
IF($ins_sql) {
  echo 'Inserted new record.';
}ELSE{
  echo 'Insert Failed.';
}
?>
```

Comment: For some reason, the text "connected successfully" shows up but the query does not get executed...

Comment: Fixed ... sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian! It worked! Now i can finally begin work on the rest of my code!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I'd like to also recommend that you Sanitize/Validate user input. And create a dbconnect.php file and use require_once('path/to/dbconnect.php'); for your connections. Don't forget mysql_close($link);

Answer (score 4):

You are missing semi-colons in the first three lines.

```
$un = $_POST["u"];
$pk = $_POST["p"];
$ok = $_POST["o"];
```

Comment: oops... Did not notice that.

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

I noticed that i did not add semicolons in the first 3 lines. after doing so i got this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{'', '', '')' at line 1." Can someone explain why?

Comment: Have you changed your SQL statement in the last PHP line?

Comment: how and what should i change @Dimitry

Comment: Can you post the last line of your PHP code and provide the values of $o, $p and $u? That would help.

Comment: $o, $p and $u are provided by the user through post method from index.html form

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual query you're executing. Maybe it's best you create a separate question for just the SQL. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

This way you will see all errors that you made syntactically or even within your SQL.

Comment: This isn't considered a solution, but troubleshooting/debugging; more a comment in my books, which was already outlined in "comments".

Comment: I noticed that i did not add semicolons in the first 3 lines. after doing so i got this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{'', '', '')' at line 1." Can someone explain why?

Comment: If I remember correctly your SQL should look like so:
`mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, occupation) VALUES ('$u', '$p', '$o')");`

Also notice I used **mysqli_query** instead of **mysql_query** as the second one is deprecated and will eventually throw more errors at you afterwards.

Comment: No Phil M. It is not the mysqli extension. I know this for sure beccause when i performed test queries, it worked perfectly. The test queries did not use mysqli.

Comment: You got me wrong then. I did not only change the command, but further I changed the variables and how they were passed inside this string pattern. Read over the code again.